# Xcode 7 update unavailable on AppStore

Tags: ios, macos, ios-appstore, xcode, apple-store

I have been seeing on web that latest update for Xcode -Xcode 7 beta release has arrived. I currently have xcode 6.4 and i cannot see any update on Appstore. Where can i get it?

Comment: Note it is not really the latest update but a beta (or currently GM) of what will become the next update - so only use if you can manage a beta - e.g. you can release the results of a build to others

Comment: Thanks @Mark for info. Can u explain "if you can manage a beta" as in what complexities it holds?
ps- I am new to iOS.

Comment: You cannot publish from a beta, only from a release.

Comment: Betas are there for you to test for Apple - so you need to be able to deal with bugs and missing features then rerun them in production Xcode and report them to Apple and there will be some. If you are new to iOS I would not do this as you would not know if it is your understanding or the beta that is wrong

Comment: Well, Thanks for guiding @Mark . This helped me take a decision :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Apple Developer Downloads page - https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

The App store doesn't have Xcode 7 yet since it's still Golden Master status and not released to the world via the App Store downloads.

Comment: Thanks. Why is it not available on appstore?? And do i need a developer ID for downloading it or my Apple ID would work?

Comment: It is not available as it is a beta

Comment: Betas are not generally available on the App Store; some are available if you are signed up to the beta program, but Xcode isn't one of them. https://developer.apple.com/xcode/